# Mongodb string match regex

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I have a few mongodb docs like below:

```
{
    ...
    ipAddress: "1.2.3.4"
},
{
    ...
    ipAddress: "1.2.3.44,1.2.5.7"
}
```

The ipAddress is a string field that can contain many IPs that are separated by comma. (`"1.2.3.4,1.3.5.7,2.4.6.8"` etc)

I would like to retrieve a mongo document that matches a particular IP. For which, I try the below query:

```
collection.findOne({
    ipAddress: new RegExp (<<the_ip>>)
});
```

However, while debugging my app, I realized that the above query matches and finds anything that has `the_ip` and not just the exact `the_ip`

Eg.
If I have two documents that have IPs as 1.2.2.2 and 1.2.2.22 and I search for regexp 1.2.2.2, I've noticed that it always matches and returns 1.2.2.22. I feel this is expected since technically the regexp is doing it's job.

However this is not the desired outcome. How do I do a full **exact** IP match?

Thanks.

Comment: try to add delimiters to the ip address `(^|,)<<the_ip>>(,|$)`

Comment: `many IPs that are separated by comma` - a better option would be to use an array and `$elemMatch` to find a specific IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to do two things:

1. Add delimiters to the IP address
2. Escape dots in the address

For (1) do:

```
(^|,)<<the_ip>>(,|$)
```

That requires that IP is preceded by the (`^`) assertion at the beginning of the string or a comma and that IP is followed by a comma or the (`$`) assertion at the end of the string.

For (2) substitute dots by `\.` in the IP string.

```
"1.2.3.4".replace(/\./g, "\\.")
```

Dot in regexp means 'any character but new line', so if you don't replace it, you may accidentally match some invalid strings (e.g. `1a1a1a1`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sOeD9E/1/)

Comment: This works. However, is there any specific reason I need to escape the dots?

Comment: This won't match in this particular case, which is what is shown in the question: https://regex101.com/r/sOeD9E/3

Comment: But the question is not about searching in a JSON string, but in mongo document. It needs to match in a field that has IPs separated by commas, with a special case of handling beginning and end of the string. The data you use in the example is not correct.

Comment: If that is the case then I’m confused why the OP would show that in question. Regardless of that I’m not sure your regex would match anyway (not at computer so unfortunately can’t test). If I’m wrong about that then apologies.

Comment: It's looking inside a field named `ipAddress` not whole document. Read question carefully @l'L'l

Comment: I think that OP wanted to show the DB structure (mongo documents are basically JSONs). When you query a mongo collection with regex, you use `collection.findOne({ key: new RegExp (pattern)});` and pattern is matched only to values for a given key.

Comment: @mrzasa is correct. I'm searching a mongo collection using findOne. I can edit the question based on what is causing the confusion.

Comment: Ah, well the confusion was here apparently; so yours would indeed match “1.2.2.2,1.2.3.4,1.2.2.2”? Just clarifying... apparently the quotes are not a factor as well I’m guessing.

Comment: @mrzasa: If you do an edit to your answer I can change my vote.

Comment: AFAIR IPs are in a string field, so quotes are not a part of the stirng and in this case the pattern words correctly, because it is run on `1.2.2.2,1.2.3.4,1.2.2.2` not on `"1.2.2.2,1.2.3.4,1.2.2.2"`. I'm not sure what  I need to edit, could you clarify?